# What kind of component is that?

Tags: identification

I found the following part on a circuit board, but I have never seen anything like it before and I am curious.

[image: Picture of the part in question]

The blue part is about 1cm long, 5mm high, 4mm thick, and vaguely cylindrically shaped.

There are no further prints on the other side and the ones visible (to me) read `4.00`, some kind of round logo and `N`. I've tried to take a more detailled picture:

[image: Label closeup]

On the PCB, the part was labelled with `QRC1`.

Can someone identify this part?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a 4.0 MHz ceramic resonator with built-in load capacitors. You can use it in place of a crystal + load capacitors in most MCU (Pierce type) oscillator circuits.

The center pin goes to ground and the other two go to input and output of the on-chip oscillator (doesn't matter which goes to input and which to output). Similar to a [Murata](https://www.murata.com/%7E/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/timingdevice/ceralock/p16e.ashx) part CSTLS4M00G56Z.

Comment: That makes sense :) I was wondering where the clock signal was coming from on that PCB but I didn't associate this component with being a clock, as I have never seen ceramic resonators before. Thanks for the quick reply!